# creating short line JavaScript for a tumblr visit counter

Tags: javascript, tumblr, hitcounter

I mixed around with other sample stuff and came up with this code:

```
</head>    
    <li><a id="counter" href="/"><img src="http://s1.freehostedscripts.net/ghitcounter.php?site=ID294699&s=94"></a>
</ol>
```

I want it to show a counter on my tumblr page, when it uses  however, it comes up with a blank image instead of using the changing image on the actual link.

Any help would be appreciated, I am a noob to Java but I do know Python and a little of html.

So, just to re-iterate what happens,

[image]

And I would like it to display the counter.

Comment: Diego is right, mark his answer as a correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Java question. The above url points to a snippet of JavaScript, not an image. You want something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s1.freehostedscripts.net/ghitcounter.php?site=ID294699&s=94"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, for reference, I wrapped it all up into this:

`<li><a id="counter" href="/"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://s1.freehostedscripts.net/ghitcounter.php?site=ID294699&s=94"></script></a></li>`

It needed to be one line and I just pasted it into the source edit. Sorry for the mixup of Java and JavaScript. Hope someone else will be able to use this code, instead of supplying an email to get 8 lines of code for a simple view counter.

Comment: All someone would need to do to use this code is to retrieve a new counter link (I got one from here) http://freehostedscripts.net/ghcget.php?id=style94 and then take out the physical link wrapped in src="http://x"